# How to say that I ranked first in my last year of high school in my country?

Tags: sentence-structure

Is it correct to say:

> I came in first in my last year ... (etc)

And what is the difference between "I came in first" and "I came first..."?

Comment: To _come in first_ is usually reserved for races; _come first_ has a far wider idiomatic distribution. I'd choose it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like

> ***I was number one in my class***

or

> ***I was the top (or top-ranked/highest ranked) student***

or

> ***I was the head of my graduating class***

Not sure what you mean by *the difference between it and* ***I came first...***

Comment: I proposed an edit to clarify. I think "it" refers to "I came in first"--that is, OP wanted to know the difference between "I came first" and "I came IN first"

Comment: Yup, @AleksandrH, that must be it.

Comment: thank you so much for your clarifications guys . you've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to say this would be as follows, even though @freeling10 has pointed out some alternatives that also work:

> I graduated at the top of my class

As Edwin noted in the comments, "came first" and "finished first" are usually used in the context of races and competitions. And while school is definitely competitive, the phrases are not commonly used in that context.